# Jenkins groovy postbuild alternative

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, post-build

You may know that the **Postbuild Script plugin** is labeled deprecated in 1.62. Link:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration#migrating-to-162

I'm using it to do several things such as to read the log file and do tasks when it contains a line matching regexp.

Do you know a good job DSL alternative to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been replaced by Pipeline plugin in Jenkins 2.x, and a jenkinsfile could be a option in new version.